# working with C# arrays (memory, efficiency, speed)

Tags: c#

When working with an array (of bytes but could be anything) how do these two approaches compare in terms of efficiency, speed, etc. Why would one prefer one over the other?

First approach

```
byte[] myArray=new byte[100];

useArray(myArray);
useArray(myArray);
useArray(myArray);

//where

void useArray(byte[] MyArray)
{
   //do something with the elements of MyArray
}
```

Second Approach

```
byte[] myArray=new byte[100];

myArray= useArray2(myArray);
myArray= useArray2(myArray);
myArray= useArray2(myArray);
//where

byte[] useArray2(byte[] MyArray)
{
    byte[] tempArray= new byte[100];
   //do EXACTLY the same as useArray but store the results in tempArray 
   return tempArray;
}
```

Take into account that the option 2 is leaving memory to be garbage collected at some point in time, everytime it calls useArray2.
Also the functions are going to be called repeatedly.

So which is more efficient, or preferable?

Comment: so i spent a bunch of time doing speed tests and the lists actually outperformed arrays and I consulted someone I know and .net spent so much time optimizing list they actually do outperform when indexing! so it kindof obsoletes arrays in c#

Comment: why not measure the speed, but at first glance the second one is doing twice the work

Comment: Your two approaches do different things. We have no idea what "do something with the elements means" - for all we know option one is O(scary) and option two is constant time.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I've not heard of O(scary) before. Is that similar to O(?) ? :-)

Comment: @Blorgbeard They both do the same thing. The difference being the first one stores the result in the original array and the second one in the tempArray

Comment: @john probably it is something like O(hmygod)  :P

Comment: so the most important question is - do you need to preserve the original contents of the array? If not then do the first one. Otherwise use Array.Copy to clone it and pass the clone to the same function

Comment: Adding a variation to @pm100's assertion; if the array content can be changed from its initial value (perhaps, multiple times without concern) OR is not ever going to be changed, THEN using a pointer reference would be even more efficient as this does not send a copy to the function, but rather sends a pointer to the memory address of the array. (i.e. - less memory allocation in either approach, although I tend to favor the First)

Answer (score 1):

Let's see. Your first example allocates a single, 100-byte array.

Your second example allocates four 100-byte arrays, all of which will need to be deallocated. And you may or may not be copying data between those arrays.

Isn't it clear that the first is more efficient?

Comment: i only see 3 arrays

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought from the very first moment. But I have heard people advocating for the second form( use return to return values). so I wish for a clear advice

Comment: @pm100: Count again.

Comment: @KansaiRobot: There are cases where returning the array might make sense. But you've given no reason why that would be better in your example. And you asked about efficiency.

Comment: @JonathanWood Thanks. I would like to learn which cases would those be?

Comment: @KansaiRobot: It just depends on the situation. For example, if a method needed to perform a calculation to determine how big the array needed to be, then it would make sense to have that method allocate the array (since the caller won't know what size to make it.) But if the caller needed to access the array, then the method would need to return the array that was allocated.

Comment: oh yes, i see lots

Comment: @pm100: Four exactly. I have no idea what you are going on about.

Comment: @JonathanWood violently agreeing with you (I say lots cos I see an implicit ... after the userArray2 calls)

Comment: " But I have heard people advocating " - then direct your question to those people!